# Order of items and type convertions with pythons BIF zip() and unzip()

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this:

```
a = d[:3]
>>> a
[[90, 26.7328829998, 131075.449348, 473898.809493],
 [90, 78.2985549184, 131116.812991,473929.491012],
 [90, 132.4760969, 131157.881628, 473964.821961]]
```

To change it's order I use the BIF `zip` in combination with the `*`-operator. This get's me a list of tuples:

```
>>> b =zip(*a)
>>> b
[(90, 90, 90),
 (26.7328829998, 78.2985549184, 132.4760969),
 (131075.449348, 131116.812991, 131157.881628),
 (473898.809493, 473929.491012, 473964.821961)]
```

I don't only want to restore the original order of the items, like:

```
>>> c = zip(*b)
>>> c
[(90, 26.7328829998, 131075.449348, 473898.809493),
 (90, 78.2985549184, 131116.812991, 473929.491012),
 (90, 132.4760969, 131157.881628, 473964.821961)]
```

but also want to get back the original type, e.g. a **list of lists**. But neither `zip(*list(b))` nor `list(zip(*b))` do the trick (I wasn't expecting the second snippet to). Does anyone know how to get there without looping through the list!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`izip` returns a generator so you won't loop through twice when you create `c`. In Python 3 `zip` (also `map`, `filter`, etc.)  returns a generator by default and `izip` has been removed.

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> a = [[90, 26.7328829998, 131075.449348, 473898.809493], [90, 78.2985549184, 131116.812991,473929.491012], [90, 132.4760969, 131157.881628, 473964.821961]]
>>> b = zip(*a)
>>> c = map(list, izip(*b))
>>> c
[[90, 26.7328829998, 131075.449348, 473898.809493], [90, 78.2985549184, 131116.812991, 473929.491012], [90, 132.4760969, 131157.881628, 473964.821961]]
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Actually I used `izip` before [(the pairwise recipe)](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)...Very nice indeed to use a generator here.

Comment: @larsvegas No problem, I also use `pairwise` and `grouper` all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these instead:

Using map:

```
c = map(list, zip(*b))
```

Or list comprehension:

```
c = [list(i) for i in zip(*b)]
```

Comment: Well, I didn't want to loop through the list...But thanks for mentioning map()